# SQL CASE How do I correct assign a value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

First, I would like to say I have already spent the due time and diligence on my part by watching videos, using other sources, and reading other posts and answers on SOF before asking this and have been unable to find a solution.

The issue I am running into, in a particular case, is a certain type is being passed in, which would require the use of LIKE as the specific type itself will not match anything as three types use the one type, say 'painting' in this situation. The database has a 'painting small' and 'painting large.'

Code

```
// I tried this
CASE WHEN type = 'painting' THEN inventory.type LIKE '%'+type+'%' ELSE inventory.type = type END
```

I keep running into the "An expression of a non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected. There are a few other variations I have tried as well as IF ELSE, however, I run into the same issue. Someone else may be able to word this question better.

I mainly want to be pointed in the right direction and receive clarification on what I am doing wrong.

Thank you

Comment: It's good you try to explain your issue, but I think you should show sample data and expected result, please.

Comment: `case` is an *expression*, it returns a single scalar value, you are misunderstanding how to use it. Please provide some data that explains your criteria.

Comment: Presumably this is part of a `WHERE`; just "bin" the `CASE` and use explicit `AND`/`OR` logic.

Comment: Your `CASE` expression results in `inventory.type LIKE '%'+type+'%'` or `inventory.type = type`, and both these expressions finally result in a boolean value (TRUE or FALSE or NULL). But SQL Server has no boolean data type, so it cannot handle this case expression result, hence the error.

Comment: Your are using the case statement wrong, THEN expects an value expression, I presume you want to assign the inventory.type a value using the case statement. something like this inventory.type = CASE WHEN inventory.type like '%painting%' THEN 'painting' ELSE 'type' END

Comment: Show the complete statement. Is this a query? Then is this case expression in the select clause or in the where clause or where else? Or is this an update statement? Do you want to update the column type in your table? Show the whole statement, so we see what you are trying t achieve and can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your query. Rather than the `CASE` expression itself I'm going to address the less obvious problem, your lack of prefixing. Take this clause:

```sql
inventory.type LIKE '%'+type+'%'
```

This could likely either error, due to an ambiguous column name, or resolve to `inventory.type LIKE '%'+inventory.type+'%'`; obviously the latter is going to *always* be true unless the column `type` has the value `NULL`. **Always** prefix your column names, especially when your query contains 2+ tables.

As for the actual problem, this is presumably part of a `WHERE`, therefore use `OR` and `AND` logic:

```sql
WHERE (({Other Table Prefix}.[type] = 'painting' AND inventory.[type] LIKE '%' + {Other Table Prefix}.[Type] + '%')
   OR  ({Other Table Prefix}.[type] != 'painting' AND inventory.[type] = {Other Table Prefix}.[Type]))
```

Obviously, you need to appropriately replace `{Other Table Prefix}` with the correct prefix.

Comment: Well spotted. If `{Other Table Prefix}.[type]` can be null then this must also be considered, e.g. `OR ( ({Other Table Prefix}.[type] != 'painting' OR {Other Table Prefix}.[type] IS NULL) AND ...`.

Comment: Thank you; For the one expression, I forgot to include the table name when I wrote the initial code; it should have been:
`inventory.type LIKE '%'+item.type+'%'`
Your solution will help me a lot. Thank you again.

Comment: In an ideal world, I'd use `{Other Table Prefix}.[type] IS DISTINCT FROM 'painting'` @ThorstenKettner , but I doubt the OP is using SQL Server 2022, considering RTM only came out yesterday.

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to be in the

```
   LIKE '%'+type+'%'
```

where LIKE may be returning a boolean value.

Comment: no case when expects there a scalar value not an equation

Comment: So you feel that `ELSE inventory.type = type` isn't a problem?

Comment: No I agree 100% with you. I was making the observation that evaluation could return an boolean instead of the value of 'type'.

Comment: A `CASE` expression *can't* return a Boolean, @Winston , the data type doesn't exist in SQL Server and a `CASE` is designed to return a *scalar value* *not* a Boolean result.

Comment: @Larnu I wasn't referring to the case statement itself but rather the value found within the query which returns the boolean. I'm well aware of how a case statement works.

Comment: `CASE` **expression**, @Winston ; if it is *were* a `CASE` statement it *could* return a boolean result but as I mentioned T-SQL doesn't support those.

Comment: @Larnu - yes a case is boolean by nature